# How to draw multiple shapes using Matlab vision toolbox and step function?

Tags: matlab, drawing, computer-vision

I'm trying to insert 2 shapes (circle and rectangle) to an image using these functions. But I'm unable to do that. 
Here's my code

```
J = step(shapeInserter, I, bbox); %bbox is rectangle which is already defined
J = step(shapeInserter, I, circle); %circle is circle which is already defined
imwrite(J,'image.jpg','jpg'); % it draws only the circle
```

I have a long way which is to save the rectange image then load again to draw the circle and resave. Which i wish to avoid as it's really time consuming.

I'm trying to do something like this (similar to the plotting graph function)

```
hold on
%draw circle
%draw rectangle
hold off
imwrite(J,'image.jpg','jpg');
```

Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vision.ShapeInserter` object has a property `Shape`, which can either be set to

- `'Rectangles'`
- `'Circles'`
- `'Lines'`
- `'Polygons'`

By default, it is set to `'Rectangles'`. To use the same ShapeInserter object to place a circle, you will have to release it first by calling `release(shapeInserter);` and modifying the Shape property by `set(shapeInserter,'Shape','Circles')`. Then you can call the step method again to insert the circle.

Here is a small example:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
rectangle = int32([10,10,50,60]);
circle = int32([200,200,40]);
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Fill',true);

J = step(shapeInserter,I,rectangle);

release(shapeInserter);
set(shapeInserter,'Shape','Circles');
K = step(shapeInserter,J,circle);

imshow(K);
```

[image: Result]

Comment: perfect! Didn't know i have to release it and set. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I'm a total noob to Matlab Image stuff but here is some very strait forward way of doing it :

```
   frame=imread( '/home/omido/DeepLearning/matlab_segmentation/track/track/Image2.jpg' );
        result = insertShape(frame, 'FilledRectangle', [100,100,100,100], 'Color', 'green');
result = insertShape(result, 'FilledRectangle',  [200,200,200,200]  , 'Color', 'yellow');
        imshow(result);
```

and this is the result:
[image]

and as in the previous answer there are multiple shapes, you can find them [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html).